# How to insert first table run time values in 2 nd table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have table A column looks below

```
> id, name, salary
> 
> Max+1(10) ,'aa',100 max+1(11), 'bb',200 . .like that i have 10 record
> is there . Max+(21),'xx',1000
```

Now 10 rows is inserted without any problem its fine .

2nd table looks below

```
p_id,age,id

p_id max+1 (41) ,30,(here i need to insert same id from A table 1st record(Max+1(10)))
p_id max+1 (42) ,31,(here i need to insert same id from A table 2nd record(Max+1(11)))
p_id max+1 (43) ,32,(here i need to insert same id from A table 3rd record(Max+1(12)))
.
.
.
.
```

likewise i need to insert 10 rows in loop. Thanks .

Comment: really dont understand what you tried to achieve. can you rephrase your question

Comment: For eg: A table id column values is generated based on max id+1 .like that i need to insert 5 record .
Consider A table have already 50 record .so my 5 record is inserted like 51,52,53,54,55.- its fine inserted correctly .

once 51 record is inserted in A table same record need to insert in to B table also .
like wise i need to insert all 52,53,54,55 record in B table ID columns. Need to achive with out trigger.

Comment: so you should try for triggers for your requirement. when you try to insert into another table

Comment: Need to achive without trigger . Need to prepare anonymous bolck .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stored procedure and don't get the `MAX()+1` value, use a sequence:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c141a7/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id      NUMBER(20,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  name    VARCHAR2(200),
  salary  NUMBER(12,2)
)
/

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  p_id    NUMBER(20,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  age     NUMBER(3,0),
  id      NUMBER(20,0) REFERENCES table1 (id)
)
/

CREATE SEQUENCE table1__id__seq
/
CREATE SEQUENCE table2__p_id__seq
/

CREATE PROCEDURE add_Details(
  in_name   TABLE1.NAME%TYPE,
  in_salary TABLE1.SALARY%TYPE,
  in_age    TABLE2.AGE%TYPE
)
IS
  p_id TABLE1.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1 ( id, name, salary )
  VALUES ( table1__id__seq.NEXTVAL, in_name, in_salary )
  RETURNING id INTO p_id;

  INSERT INTO table2 ( p_id, age, id )
  VALUES ( table2__p_id__seq.NEXTVAL, in_age, p_id );
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
BEGIN
  add_Details( 'aa', 100, 30 );
  add_Details( 'bb', 200, 31 );
  add_Details( 'cc', 300, 32 );
END;
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c141a7/3/1)**:

```
| ID | NAME | SALARY |
|----|------|--------|
|  1 |   aa |    100 |
|  2 |   bb |    200 |
|  3 |   cc |    300 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT * FROM table2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c141a7/3/2)**:

```
| P_ID | AGE | ID |
|------|-----|----|
|    1 |  30 |  1 |
|    2 |  31 |  2 |
|    3 |  32 |  3 |
```